# show all divs listed in Select menu

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I have a select menu of countries that is generated based on the user logged in.  For whatever countries are listed, I want those country divs to be displayed, while all other country divs not referenced in the select menu should be hidden.  Whats the best way to do this?

The closest I got so far is using OnChange to display divs one at a time based on the dropdown menu selection (see code snippit). But I want it to display "all" divs in the menu without having having to click anything, while the remaining divs not listed in the menu should be hidden. Thanks in advance!

Edit: added code

```js
function fctCheck(countries) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByName("selector");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
     elems.item(i).style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(countries).style.display = "block";
   }
```

```html
<select id="country" onchange="fctCheck(this.value);">
        <option value="America">America</option>
        <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
  </select>  
    
    
    <div id="America" name="selector" style="display:none">America Content</div>  
    <div id="Australia" name="selector" style="display:none">Australia Content</div> 
    <div id="China" name="selector" style="display:none">China Content</div>
    <div id="India" name="selector" style="display:none">India Content</div>
    <div id="Japan" name="selector" style="display:none">Japan Content</div>
```

Comment: Could you give us your code please?

Comment: Hi D Russell, welcome to SO.  Please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question.  In it's current form, your question is too broad and will be closed.  You need to ask about a specific problem and produce the code in your question about the attempt you have made and where you are having problems

Comment: I see the code works as I think I understood you wanted. Can you elaborate the issue? @D. Russell

Comment: @luk492 Well currently it shows America content if America is selected, Australia content if Australia is selected, India content if India is selected.  However I want all three America, Australia, and India content to be displayed without having to select anything in the dropdown list.

Comment: @D. Russell So initially it should display all countries, but if some country is selected what should happen?

Comment: @luk492 I guess if user selects a specific country, the other country divs can be hidden.